# JQuery Script only runs once, then only works after page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a menu for a one page website, where when the user clicks in a menu item, the css position of menu and logo gets fixed (to scroll with the page), and after the animate it gets position absolute. 
It's a very simple code, but I don't know why it only works once, after this, it only works if I refresh the page.

Heres the function

```
    <script>
        function ScrollTo( obj ){

            var topOffset = 0;
            topOffset = parseInt($(obj).offset().top);

            $('#menu').css('position','fixed');
            $('#logo').css('position','fixed');


            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(obj).offset().top }, 1000, function(){
                                                    $('#menu').css('position','absolute');
                                                    $('#logo').css('position','absolute');
                                                    $('#menu').css('margin-top', topOffset+'px');
                                                    $('#logo').css('margin-top', topOffset+'px');
                                    });

        }           
    </script>
```

Comment: How are you calling it? Did you check the console for errors? Did you try debugging it with a browser?

Comment: I tried to call it by two ways, first in a script like $(document).ready() ... 
where every menu item has a $('#menu-item').click(function(){ ScrollTo('.test') }); and in the li element, by onClick="ScrollTo('.test');".
I tried that, but in here doesn't display any errors ...

Comment: Is this code in your `head` section? Or before the `</body>`? Where do you call it and how?

Comment: try to put it on jsfiddle, so i can help you. please

Comment: add a loop and or reset function